# What does this expression mean float pay(float hoursWorked) const;

Tags: c++, constants

What does this expression mean float pay(float hoursWorked) const;

In C, if we return a const one, const float f ()... what does this mean by putting const in the last

Comment: It's not an expression, it's a member function declaration.

Comment: yes, it is declaration, but what does that mean by putting const there

Comment: The question along with your comment on the answer suggests that it's time you invest in a good book

Answer (score 1):

It is a declaration of non-static member function of some class

```
float pay(float hoursWorked) const;
```

The last qualifier const means that the object for which this function is called is considered as a constant object and this function may no change its data members except those that were declared with specifier mutable.

Comment: thanks, I also search static function member. what does static mean. It seems that static function could not change the private member?

Comment: @user3341953 No it is a wrong statement. static member functions as non-static member functions can change private data members of a class where they are defined. Static member functions are called without an instantiation of an object. They are "class-wide" functions while non-static member functions are "object-wide" functions.